# Prove: If $\{s_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy in a metric space $\langle M, \rho\rangle$, then sequence $\{\rho(s_1, s_n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Show that if $\left\{s_{n}\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence in a metric space $\langle M, \rho\rangle$, then the sequence of real numbers $\left\{\rho\left(s_1, s_{n}\right)\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded.

I started with: Suppose $\left\{\rho\left(s_1, s_{n}\right)\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is not bounded, then, for any $M>0$ however large, there is some $N_M \in \mathbb N$ such that $\rho(s_1,s_{N_M})>M$. Then how can we reach at violating Cauchy condition?

I think triangular inequality has some role in.

Comment: What is $s$ in this context?

Comment: @PabloHerrera It doesn't really matter what $s$ is.

Comment: @uniquesolution but so $s$ is any member of $M$?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I corrected it.

Comment: @PabloHerrera   yes, $s$ is arbitrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\{s_n\}$ is Cauchy, there exists $N$ s.t. $\rho(s_n,s_N)\le 1$ for all $n>N$. Thus, for $n>N$,
$$
\rho(s,s_n)\le \rho(s, s_N)+\rho(s_n,s_N)\le \rho(s, s_N)+1.
$$